# How and where to check certain Apache Camel settings

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have a Camel-based app that publishes/subscribes messages to/from an ActiveMQ instance with routes like:

```
<from uri="activemq:myQueue" />
```

or:

```
<to uri="activemq:someOtherQueue" />
```

I'm trying to determine if I've inadvertently set my app up in "synchronous mode", which happens when either:

- `ActiveMQConnectionFactory#setAlwaysSyncSend` is true; or
- The "`MessageProducer`" is set to "Persistent"

I *believe* that, sans Camel, I would ordinarily be setting these properties manually. Introducing Camel as the ActiveMQ client here, not sure how/where to go to find what the value of these properties are. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You configure these values when you add the component by setting them on the connection URI that is passed to the ActiveMQ component.  This [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) on the Camel website shows you how its done.

The ActiveMQ client does some of its own optimizations to improve performance on sends by choosing to use async over sync in some cases.  This is [documented here](http://activemq.apache.org/async-sends.html) and is worth a read.

So you would configure the component when you add it via code like this:

```
camelContext.addComponent("activemq", activeMQComponent("tcp://localhost:61616?jms.alwaysSyncSend=true"));
```

The ActiveMQConnectionFactory configuration options are documented in detail [here](http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html) and the options applicable to Transports are [here](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html)

Comment: Thanks @Tim Bish (+1) - hmmm I seem to be getting somewhere now.  I see that the ActiveMQ component doesn't add any new options and that all of the [JMS options](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) apply to ActiveMQ. So, looking at those JMS options, I'm seeing a few that *kind of* resemble `alwaysSyncSend` (i.e., `asyncConsumer`, `asyncStartListener` and `asyncStopListener`), however I'm not seeing *any* that resemble a `MessageProducer`. Any ideas? I feel like I'm so close, but am still having a tough time seeing "the forest through the trees" here. Thanks again!

Comment: Additionally, `asyncConsumer` (which sounds the *most* like `alwaysSyncSend`) defaults to `false`. So, if this is the property that corresponds to `alwaysSyncSend`, and I'm not explicitly setting it to `true`, then doesn't that mean that my client is configured in "synchronous mode"?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit to get to what it is you are really trying to do?  Or what is not working the way you want it to?  I'm having a hard time understanding your issue so hard to form a good answer.  Read the link I added on the AMQ client and its use of async sends for some cases.  Most of this stuff you generally don't need to mess with.

Comment: Thanks again - I'm simply trying to determine if the way I have configured Camel/JMS/ActiveMQ has resulted with me being in "synchronous mode", which (according to your answer of another question of mine) happens when `ActiveMQConnectionFactory#isAlwaysSyncSend()` returns true, or if the Camel `MessageProducer` is set to "Persistent" (somehow). So I'm trying to figure out which Camel-JMS option correlates to `isAlwaysSyncSend()`, and `MessageProducer#Persistent`.

Comment: Camel JMS deliveryPersistent option controls the MessageProducer DeliveryMode, default is true.  There is no correlation to ActiveMQConnectionFactory alwaysSyncSend as that is ActiveMQ specific and is set on the ActiveMQ Camel component URI when you add it.  Default for that one is false.

Comment: Thanks again @Tim Bish (+1) - only 1 concern her: If I understand what you're telling me, you're saying that I can write `<to uri="activemq:myQueue?alwaysSyncSend=true"/>`. Is that correct? If so, **where is that documented??** There's no mention of it on the Camel-ActiveMQ page. Thanks again for all your great help thus far!

Comment: The ActiveMQ Camel component page calls out the fact that you can set properties on the BrokerUri for the component.  If you follow the links to the Broker URI page you find documentation on the various URI setting for transports and the ActiveMQConnectionFactory.  If you think there needs to be more documentation then feel free to contribute or discuss on the AMQ mailing list.

Comment: Thanks again, but are we looking at the same thing? I am looking at [this page here](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) which only states (with respect to Camel options/properties): `See Options on the JMS component as all these options also apply for this component.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26059/discussion-between-tim-bish-and-dirtymikeandtheboys)